# SAML Error Request not signed. Policy requires signed authentication requests

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, saml, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Releated post: [SAML Error: Request not signed. Policy requires signed authentication requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77341286/saml-error-request-not-signed-policy-requires-signed-authentication-requests#new-answer).

I followed the steps in this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/saml-service-provider?tabs=windows&pivots=b2c-custom-policy.

However, on the last step, when trying to test my SAML setup with the provided Test App, I get the following error:

[image: error]

Could you please guide me on what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/saml-identity-provider-technical-profile).

There are several options for signing. You can turn the options on and off.

Comment: Hi, i am new to azure and i don't know what to change here. Could you please help me on what are the changes required?

Comment: https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/connecting-the-samltest-application-to-azure-ad-b2c-as-an-idp-27c3ab7947f6

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. It's working now.